# Closed form of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\alpha \, n)}{n!}$

Tags: summation, closed-form

How would I find the closed form of

$$ f(\alpha) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\alpha \, n)}{n!}$$

My old pal Wolfram tells me that

$$ f(\alpha) = \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\alpha)}\cos(\sin(\alpha))$$

I've attempted writing out the first couple terms for different values of $\alpha$, but I haven't quite figured out how to arrive at the result.

Comment: Use De Moivre's Theorem $ \exp(i \alpha) =\cos \theta + i\sin \theta$ and the look at the real part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{\cos (n\alpha)}{n!}+i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n\alpha)}{n!}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now by De Moivre's theorem this equals
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{e^{(ni\alpha)}}{n!}= e^{e^{i\alpha}}=e^{\cos \alpha+i\sin \alpha} =e^{\cos \alpha} e^{+i\sin \alpha} =e^{\cos \alpha} (\cos (\sin \alpha)+i\sin (\sin\alpha))
\end{eqnarray*}
Now equate the real parts & we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{\cos (n\alpha)}{n!}=e^{\cos \alpha} \cos (\sin \alpha).
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

> $$\cos(\alpha n)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(e^{i\alpha}\right)^n+\left(e^{-i\alpha}\right)^n\right)$$

Alternatively, this can be written as (when $\alpha$ is real) as

> $\cos(\alpha n)$ is the real part of $\left(e^{i\alpha}\right)^n$.